# How to send data to list

Tags: firebase, flutter

I tried to give the data to the list(this is all happening inside the widget), but it gives an error. I can't figure out why.

```
uid = widget.uid;
List<String> ref;
ref.add(uid);
```

This is the error - The method 'add' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: add("TK4DCxUTnnThPhyuLIEFFFBNMuk1")

Comment: try the list to do this List<String> ref = [];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate it first:

```
uid = widget.uid;
List<String> ref=[];
ref.add(uid);
```

The error is self explanatory, get used to reading and understanding errors. Your error is telling you that you tried to call a method `.add` on an object which is currently equal to null. It points to no place in memory, it only booked a name for it in memory, and that name is `ref`. But what does `ref` contain? How does it look like? Nobody knows, therefore it's assigned a value of `null`. When you use `=[ ]`, it points to a place in memory which is an empty list. Your error goes away. You will encounter this with many objects. If you are using null safety, this error would've been avoided also. The IDE will not have allowed you to declare it as `ref;`

Comment: i was thinking how to solve about 30 minutes. thanks a lot

Comment: You're most welcome, I added an explanation.